# Haskell: List Comprehensions and higher-order functions

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I've tried to transform the following list comprehension:

```
f xs = [ x+8 | (x,_) <- xs ]
```

using higher-order functions.

My first solution was:

```
f' xs = map (\(x,_) -> x+8) xs
```

After I tried various other approaches, I found out that the following also works:

```
f' xs = map((+8).fst) xs
```

Both versions of `f'` give the same (correct) output, but I don't understand why `(+8).fst` is equal to `\(x,_) -> x+8` when using `map` on a list of tuples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `fst` is

```
fst :: (a, b) -> a
fst (a, _) = a
```

and the definition of `(.)` is

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(f . g) = \x -> f (g x)
```

If we use these definitions to expand your function, we get

```
f' xs = map ((+8) . fst) xs
f' xs = map (\x -> (+8) (fst x)) xs         -- definition of (.)
f' xs = map (\x -> (+8) ((\(a, _) -> a) x)) -- definition of fst
f' xs = map (\(a, _) -> (+8) a)             -- we can move the pattern matching
f' xs = map (\(a, _) -> a + 8)              -- expand section
```

Comment: Love the straightforward answer, equational reasoning ftw. +1

Answer (score 4):

> Both versions of f' give the same (correct) output, but I don't understand why `(+8).fst` is equal to `(x,_) -> x+8` when using map on a list of tuples.

The type of `fst` is:

```
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

and what it does is it takes the first element of a pair (a tuple of two elements).

The type of `(+8)` is:

```
(+8) :: Num a => a -> a
```

and what it does is it takes as input a `Num`, applies `+ 8` to it and returns the result.

Now, the type of `(+8) . fst` is:

```
((+8).fst) :: Num c => (c, b) -> c
```

which is the composition of `fst` and `(+8)`. Specifically it's the function that takes as input a pair, extracts the first element and adds `8` to it.

This can be easily seen by seen an example:

```
((+8).fst) (3, 'a')
-- 11
```

The same thing happens with `\ (x, _) -> x + 8`. You take a pair as input (in the lambda), pattern match the first argument to `x`, increment it by `8` and return it:

```
(\ (x, _) -> x + 8) (3, 'a')
-- 11
```

Comment: Your explanations make this very clear, unfortunately I can't accept two answers.